# Mysql Regex query to find slightly different duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a table, and it has a few columns, like ID, name, etc.  There is also a column that holds a JSON object.  Some rows got duplicated, due to a bug.  I've been trying to write a query that will find all of the duplicates.

Example of JSON:

```
    {"flowId":"63","nodeId":2,"triggerLogId":"39397","modelId":"146",...}
```

I want to be able to find a duplicate of the above, where everything is the same, except the "triggerLogId" could be two different numbers.

Example of possible duplicate JSON:

```
    {"flowId":"63","nodeId":2,"triggerLogId":"56217","modelId":"146",...}
```

I figured out a few queries to do this if the triggerLogId is the same on both rows, but I can't seem to find any regex that I can use to compare the two columns.

From what I understand, MySQL doesn't have regex back references, so I can't use those.  Is this even possible in pure MySQL?  The flowId and modelId can be various numbers, so having a list of those wont work.

Searched most of the Stack overflow questions, and tons of google results, hoping someone here will know something I haven't been able to find. :P

Will I end up having to use PHP?

Edit (Table Structure):

id  -----       int(11) Auto Increment
type--      varchar(20)
time--      bigint(20) NULL
data--      text

Comment: please post the structure of your table. are the fileds in the json text reflected in the rows' fields?

Comment: added, no, they dont.  Sadly it's just in a text field.  The "data" field in the structure is where all the JSON is.

Comment: Is there any of the Id's in the JSON data unique?

Comment: Sadly, there is nothing that can be 100% unique in the JSON data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer. This will hopefully help someone or yourself to find your answer.

Using this query you can "transform" your data values into different columns.

```
SELECT id,type,time,flowId,nodeId,triggerLogId,modelId FROM
(
SELECT *,
SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+2, LOCATE(',',data,LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+3) - (LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+2)) as flowId,
SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+2, LOCATE(',',data,LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+3) - (LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+2)) as nodeId,
SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('triggerLogId',data)+LENGTH('triggerLogId')+2, LOCATE(',',data,LOCATE('triggerLogId',data)+LENGTH('triggerLogId')+3) - (LOCATE('triggerLogId',data)+LENGTH('triggerLogId')+2)) as triggerLogId,
SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+2, LOCATE('}',data,LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+3) - (LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+2)) as modelId
FROM `my_table`
)
as foo
```

I will keep trying to find an answer to your problem and update my answer.

**UPDATE**

Does this solve your problem?

```
SELECT CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS CHAR(1000)) as duplicated_rows
FROM `test`
GROUP BY CONCAT(SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+2, LOCATE(',',data,LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+3) - (LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+2)),
                                SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+2, LOCATE(',',data,LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+3) - (LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+2)),
                                SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+2, LOCATE('}',data,LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+3) - (LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+2)))
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

**DELETE DUPLICATES**

I'm not even close to be expert in MySQL so probably (most certainly) this is not even close the best answer. In order to remove the duplicate rows and keep the **last row** (i.e. leave just the row that has the highest id) we need two steps:

1. Get the list of ids we are going to remove using this query:

   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(delete_rows) as delete_ids 
   FROM ( SELECT SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(id),1,(LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(id)) - LOCATE(',',REVERSE(GROUP_CONCAT(id))))) as delete_rows 
                   FROM test 
                   GROUP BY CONCAT(SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+2, LOCATE(',',data,LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+3) - (LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+2)), SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+2, LOCATE(',',data,LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+3) - (LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+2)), SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+2, LOCATE('}',data,LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+3) - (LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+2)) ) 
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as foo 
   GROUP BY '';
2. That query will return a list of ids like `(1,5,7,8,10)`. Copy that list in the next query:

   `DELETE FROM test WHERE id IN <copy_list_here>`

**FINAL UPDATE**

I found a way to acoomplish this using just one query.

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(delete_rows) as delete_ids 
FROM ( SELECT SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(id),1,(LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(id)) - LOCATE(',',REVERSE(GROUP_CONCAT(id))))) as delete_rows 
                FROM test 
                GROUP BY CONCAT(SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+2, LOCATE(',',data,LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+3) - (LOCATE('flowId',data)+LENGTH('flowId')+2)), SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+2, LOCATE(',',data,LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+3) - (LOCATE('nodeId',data)+LENGTH('nodeId')+2)), SUBSTR(data,LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+2, LOCATE('}',data,LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+3) - (LOCATE('modelId',data)+LENGTH('modelId')+2)) ) 
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as foo 
GROUP BY ''
));
```

Comment: Holy crap...I think that might actually do it...I didn't think it was possible!  A question, when I run the sql on my database, it does return 2 results, which I have validated to be duplicates.  But why does it only return 2 results?  Is it returning the last created one, or the one created first?

Basically it doesn't return all of the ID's, for all of the duplicates...

Comment: Right now it returns the one with the lowest `id`, AKA oldest entry. You can change it placing `ORDER BY id DESC` right after `FROM ´test´`, this way it will return the newest entry. I will try to find a way to return all the duplicates.

Comment: I have shortened the query, but it still shows exactly what you need.

Comment: Awesome, just did some double checking, and it works like a charm, and even grabs all the duplicates that i wrote a query for before!  

Is it possible to delete all but one duplicates with this type of query?  Currently going through so i can try to understand what your doing, but i'm not sure a delete * from * IN will work with a query like this?

Comment: How would you choose the one row that you want to keep?

Comment: Would want to keep the newest row, no matter what.  If i reverted to the one you posted yesterday i could just keep running it until there were no results.  But seems kinda silly to do that.

Comment: I updated my answer with a simple way to remove the duplicates you don't want. Pleas make a backup of your database before trying it, just i case.

Comment: Thanks!  Works great!  Your SQL foo is strong :P  I find it weird that you can't wrap the delete from * in around the first query, but i'm guessing it's because there's so many groups and stuff :P